# Derivation of non-linear Schrödinger equation from many-body QM

Tags: schroedinger-equation, many-body, mean-field-theory, non-linear-schroedinger

I hope this (and not MathOverflow) is the right place to post this question. I am a math student taking a methods of mathematical physics course, in which we cover the solution theory the non-linear Schrödinger equation $$i u_t+ \frac{\Delta}{2}u=\lambda|u|^{p-1}u.$$ I understand that this PDE (or some special case of it) may be derived as some mean-field limit from many-body quantum mechanics. How is this done?

Comment: This is Gross-Pitaevskii model been derived from the scratch in the paper  http://www.jetp.ac.ru/cgi-bin/dn/e_013_02_0451.pdf

Comment: Thank you! That is enough to work with.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The derivation is in the [paper](http://www.jetp.ac.ru/cgi-bin/dn/e_013_02_0451.pdf) by Pitaevskii posted in the comment above.